# Word for a place or building where martyres are kept or buried?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word denoting a place or any architechural building, where martyres are buried or kept?

By researching to get its answer, I found the term “[martyrium](http://www.yourdictionary.com/martyrium),” which is specifically used for **Christian martyres or saints**. See its definition from **yourdictionary.com**:

> **NOUN**
>
> A church or other edifice built at a site, especially a tomb, associated with a **Christian** martyr or saint.

In contrast to the term “martyrium”, I am looking for a word that denotes a place or building where martyres are kept or buried; that word shouldn't denote a specific religion or person, but a neutral one (e.g. For Muslims, Christians, etc).

Comment: There's an understandable Christian flavour to words such as these, given the history of Europe and the English language. They'd be completely understandable when applied to another religious context, and, I'd say, your best choice of word in this instance. Incidentally, there is also [_reliquary_](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/reliquary), generally a box for bits of martyrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing in English, are you not?
"martyr" is a Greco-Latin derivative. The noun ending "ium" is the Latin 3rd declension plural genitive ending. Thus, "martyrium" means "[place] of martyr." 
Since you're writing in English, which contains predominantly Greek and Latin derivatives, I see no issue in using "martyrium" to describe a resting place for martyrs both Christian and not.